# Not sure how to proceed with this in my first ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs

I've created a simple timer app in react which lets you input a number and start a countdown. Just for "learning react"-purposes I implemented an API to store timers that have been set. They're read on componentDidMount. You can delete them one by one using a button. The problem: Starting the timer is in a different component and doesnt know the state of the "RecentTimers" component. I'm unsure on how to properly do this with react.

This is the component that cares about the actual timer:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import ProgressBar from './ProgressBar';
import Input from './Input';
import Message from './Message';
import RecentTimers from './RecentTimers';

export default class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      running: false,
      secsStart: 0,
      secsRemaining: 0
    };

    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
  }

  startTimer(startValue) {
    this.setState({
      running: true,
      secsStart: startValue,
      secsRemaining: startValue
    });

    this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);

    this.saveTimer(startValue);
  }

  saveTimer(startValue) {
    Axios.post('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/svartberg/timers', {
        timestamp: + new Date(),
        seconds: startValue
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        UIkit.notification({
          message: 'Couldn\'t save the timer.<br />' + error,
          status: 'danger',
          pos: 'bottom-right'
        });
      });
  }

  tick() {
    if (this.state.running) {
      if (this.state.secsRemaining > 0) {
        this.setState({
          secsRemaining: this.state.secsRemaining - 1
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          running: false
        });
        clearInterval(this.timer);
      }
    }
  }

  renderProgress() {
    return this.state.secsRemaining <= 0
      ? <Message>Der Timer ist abgelaufen.</Message>
      : <ProgressBar
          secsRemaining={this.state.secsRemaining}
          secsStart={this.state.secsStart}
        />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="uk-container uk-container-center uk-margin-large-top uk-margin-large-bottom">
        <h1 className="uk-text-center">Simple Timer</h1>
        <Input startFunc={this.startTimer} status={this.state.running} />
        <div className="uk-text-center uk-margin-top">
          <span className="uk-text-lead">{this.state.secsRemaining}</span>{' '}
          seconds left.
        </div>
        { this.renderProgress() }
        <RecentTimers />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the component that cares about the list of recently used timers:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';

import UIkit from 'uikit';
import Icons from 'uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons';

UIkit.use(Icons);

export default class RecentTimers extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      recentTimers: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getRecentTimers();
  }

  getRecentTimers() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    Axios.get('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/svartberg/timers')
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          recentTimers: response.data.reverse()
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        UIkit.notification({
          message: 'Couldn\'t fetch recent timers.<br />' + error,
          status: 'danger',
          pos: 'bottom-right'
        });
      });
  }

  deleteRecentTimerItem(item) {
    Axios.delete('http://rest.learncode.academy/api/svartberg/timers/' + item.id)
      .then((response) => {
        this.getRecentTimers();

        UIkit.notification({
          message: 'Item deleted',
          status: 'success',
          pos: 'bottom-right'
        });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        UIkit.notification({
          message: 'Couldn\'t delete timer with ID ' + item.id + '.<br />' + error,
          status: 'danger',
          pos: 'bottom-right'
        });
      });
  }

  renderRecentTimerItems() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div className="uk-text-center"><span data-uk-spinner={''} /></div>;
    } else {
      return this.state.recentTimers.length > 0
        ? this.state.recentTimers.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleDateString()} - {new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleTimeString()} <span className="uk-margin-small-left uk-margin-small-right">|</span>  {item.seconds} Secs.
            <span onClick={this.deleteRecentTimerItem.bind(this, item)} className="uk-float-right" style={{lineHeight: 'normal'}} data-uk-icon="icon: close"></span>
          </li>
        ))
        : <p>No recent timers.</p>;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <hr />
        <div className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body">
          <h3 className="uk-card-title uk-text-center">Recent Timers</h3>
          <ul className="uk-list uk-list-divider">
            { this.renderRecentTimerItems() }
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

No idea how I tell my recent timers component that it needs to update because a new timer started and I want that timer in my list of recent timers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the timer object in the props of your `<RecentTimers timer={this.state.timer}>` this.state.timer can be updated whenever your are starting a timer and use componentWillRecieveProps to update the state of RecentTimer component whenever there is an addition of a new timer in the timer list.

Whenever you are updating a component following function will be invoked.

```
1.componentWillReceiveProps()  
2.shouldComponentUpdate()   
3.componentWillUpdate()  
4.render()  
5.componentDidUpdate()
```

You can use

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

   if(nextProps.timer){
     let recentTimer = this.state.recentTimers;
     this.setState({
        recentTimers : recentTimers.push(nextProps.timer);// this update your timers, But wont re-render the component.
     });
     //or save the timer 
   }
}
```

Or Use componentWillUpdate as this method will re-render your component,

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps , nextState){
   //Code goes here.
}
```

You can see this [blog](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-state-in-react-6f2d3cd73a0c) for more info of state handling.

Thanks,

Comment: Thx, I already thought of something like this. Isn't that kind of bad practice tho? I will try it as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, you can have a look at this [article](https://medium.com/react-ecosystem/how-to-handle-state-in-react-6f2d3cd73a0c) , which gives a good understanding about react state ecosystem.

Comment: The thing is, how do I identify if it is a new timer? You can see the tick() function in my Timer component. It gets called everytime my progress bar decreases 1 second. Therefore, componentWillReceiveProps() ind the RecentTimers component would receive the state of the Timer component every second the timer ticks. Everything in the state would be the same except the remaining seconds. How should I identify that a NEW timer STARTED?

A better trigger would be the startTimer() function in my Timer component. Everytime that function gets called, a news timer-entry will be added through the API

Comment: I now did it almost as you explained. I jist made a new variable "newTimer" that is false by dwfault and gets true when I trigger "startTimer()" which sets the "newTimer" to true. In the response of the API call I then set it back to false. In between, I call getRecentTimers() again.